# Conditionally give value to one column based on the words that another column contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe "df":

```
Patient    Condition
John       Adductor tear left
Mary       Adductor sprain left
Henry      Hamstring sprain
Lucy       Hamstring tear
```

If Adductor = 1 and Hamstring = 2, and on the other hand, tear = 1 and sprain = 2. I would like to create two columns, one for the Muscle, and another one for the injury, showing that value.
The expected result would be:

```
Patient    Condition             Muscle   Injury
John       Adductor tear left      1        1
Mary       Adductor sprain left    1        2
Henry      Hamstring sprain        2        2
Lucy       Hamstring tear          2        1
```

I'm not sure if i should split the "condition" column and then replace the words. Or use a condition, but I'm not sure how to use the condition based on a word. Any idea how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to split the condition column. You can use the following code given the assumptions:

- every row in `df` contains either `"Adductor"` or `"Hamstring"` in the `Condition` column, case sensitive.
- same thing with the words `"tear"` and `"sprain"`.

```
df["Muscle"] = df["Condition"].apply(lambda x: 1 if "Adductor" in x else 2)
```

Same thing with the `Injury` column. You can try it and let me know if you need help.

If you do not want to worry about words being in upper or lower cases, you can use:

```
df["Muscle"] = df["Condition"].apply(lambda x: 1 if "adductor" in x.lower() else 2)
```

**Update to address more than two muscle/injuries groups:**

I will give example for handling muscles, and the same goes for injuries. You can create a dictionary where the keys are the muscle names and the values are the codes you want to put in the new columns. You can write the dictionary in lower case so that you do not need to worry about letter cases in the code.

```
muscle_dict = {
    "muscle_1": 1,
    "muscle_2": 2,
    "muscle_3": 3
}
```

Now, you can do the same trick with `apply()` function but with slightly more complex function.

```
df["Muscle"] = df["Condition"].apply(lambda x: muscle_dict[x.split()[0].lower()])
```

You can make the code more readable by creating a stand alone function that takes a string that you write in the `Condition` column and return the muscle code.

```
def get_muscle_code(cond):
    # it is better to define the muscle dictionary here
    muscle = cond.split()[0].lower()
    return muscle_dict[muscle]

# above code will be 
df["Muscle"] = df["Condition"].apply(get_muscle_code)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in my full dataframe I have more than two muscular groups and more than two injuries. So, could you give me a code where I can extend it to all the muscular groups and injuries?

Comment: sure, no problem. Will you always have the first word for muscle and second word for injury?

Comment: Yes! In my native language we place first the injury and second the muscle, but, anyway, it's always the same order. And everytime the injury and the muscle is one single word each.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer. I updated it to handle multiple muscles. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've defined the dictionary with the muscular groups (the second word of my column "Condition") and I tried your code but I get: KeyError: '0'. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, any idea?

Comment: The `keyError` happens when you passed 0 to the dictionary instead of the muscle name. Could you please add the code you used and the error message to your question so I can know what went wrong? especially what line of code gives this error.

Comment: I had my missing data as a "0", so I've just added the "0" to the dictionary and it worked! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to search for specific strings in Condition column and assign values using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html).

```
import numpy as np
df['Muscle'] = np.select([df['Condition'].str.contains('Adductor'), df['Condition'].str.contains('Hamstring')], [1,2], np.nan)
df['Injury'] = np.select([df['Condition'].str.contains('tear'), df['Condition'].str.contains('sprain')], [1,2], np.nan)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using `enumerate()` and `assign()`

```
m = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(['adductor','hamstring'],1)}
i = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(['tear','sprain'],1)}

col = df['Condition'].str.split()
df.assign(Muscle = col.str[0].str.lower().map(m), Injury = col.str[1].str.lower().map(i))
```